# Locating Instagram post elements using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to return comments and usernames on an instagram post and save them to a list using python and selenium. I can't seem to locate anything.

```
comments = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@style, 'line-height: var(--base-line-clamp-line-height); --base-line-clamp-line-height: 18px;')]")

# Extract and print comments
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.get_attribute("innerText"))

driver.quit()
```

Edit: With this code I managed to return the following text:
[Currently loaded comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9kJA.png)

Can we only save the comment text from this data?

Comment: that class name looks dynamic name, are you sure "C4VMK" is always there??

Comment: I found a better way to access the text please check the image I added. I'm trying to find a distinctive attribute for the comment text but I can't find it.